# Returning Data Result to Parent Activity using Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am able to successfully transfer the string in my `ListView` in my first Activity to the `EditText` in my second Activity. I now want to edit the text and send it back to update my `ListView` in my first Activity. I basically want to have the edits be sent back to the first activity as a popup to help me test which string is being passed back

I'm not sure what Intent to put in my `onActivityResult()`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        String name = data.getExtras().getString("name");
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Here is my first Activity:

```
    public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {
        private ArrayList<String> todoItems;        
        private ArrayAdapter<String> todoAdapter;       // declare array adapter which will translate the piece of data to teh view
        private ListView lvItems;                   // attach to list view
        private EditText etNewItem;
        private final int REQUEST_CODE = 20;
        //private Intent i;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);
            etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
            lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);        // now we have access to ListView
            //populateArrayItems();                 // call function
            readItems();        // read items from file
            todoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);   //create adapter
            lvItems.setAdapter(todoAdapter);        // populate listview using the adapter 
            //todoAdapter.add("item 4");
            setupListViewListener();
            setupEditItemListener();
            onActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE, RESULT_OK, /** Intent variable **/);
        }
    private void launchEditItem(String item) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EditItemActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("itemOnList", item);     // list item into edit text
        //startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private void setupEditItemListener() {          // on click, run this function to display edit page
        lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                String text = (String) lvItems.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                launchEditItem(text);
            }

        });
    }

    private void setupListViewListener() {
        lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View item, int pos, long id) {
                todoItems.remove(pos);
                todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // has adapter look back at the array list and refresh it's data and repopulate the view
                writeItems();   
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onAddedItem(View v) {
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();
        todoAdapter.add(itemText);  // add to adapter
        etNewItem.setText("");      //clear edit text
        writeItems();       //each time to add item, you want to write to file to memorize
    }

    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>(FileUtils.readLines(todoFile));   //populate with read
        }catch (IOException e) {    // if files doesn't exist  
            todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }

    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();  //return path where files can be created for android
        File todoFile = new File(filesDir, "todo.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(todoFile, todoItems);  // pass todoItems to todoFile
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            String name = data.getExtras().getString("name");
            Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I thought about using the `Intent` from the second activity but I'm not sure how to do so.

Here is my second Activity.

```
public class EditItemActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText etEditItem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_item);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String ItemToEdit = i.getStringExtra("itemOnList");
        etEditItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEditItem);
        etEditItem.setText(ItemToEdit);
        onSubmit(etEditItem); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_item, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void DoneEdit(View v) {
        this.finish();
    }

    public void onSubmit(View v) {
        EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEditItem);
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("EditedItem", etName.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I must admit I did not read you code very carefully but is this not simply A - send text -> B (you managed this already) and then start a new A activity as dialog B - send text -> A ? Otherwise, if it is a finite set of texts that you want to do this for, then I would suggest using SharedPreferences to store and retrieve it, which makes the situation much simpler in my opinion. Then you save it once and get it in anywhere with a context.

Comment: you need `startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);` which is commented out.. any reason for that?

Comment: Um i think so. I'm still learning android dev so I'm not sure if starting a new `Intent` from B to A is the way to go but yes. Step 1 
A -send text-> B. Step 2 edit text in EditText. Step 3 send edited text from B back to A

Comment: @AmulyaKhare yes i was testing if previous functions worked. I'm not sure what to put in my `onActivityForResult()` to display what was being sent back

Comment: From first activity, use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`, rest of the code is fine, it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get result form an activity (child) you do as follow :

In the parent activity

```
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);
```

global vars of your parent activity

```
boolean backFromChild = false;
String aString;
```

then still in the parent activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // code for result
            aString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("aString");
            backFromChild = true;
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code on no result return
        }
    }
}
```

in your child you do somewhere something like that

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
//example of sending back a string to the parent.
returnIntent.putExtra("aString", aString); 
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

The thing is that `onResume` of your parent activity will be called when returning from your child. In there you have to perform the update, in your case it is to update the information of the edited text :

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (backFromChild){
         backFromChild = false;
         //do something with aString here
         Toast.makeText(this, aString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Basically, in the `onActivityResult` I get the info back from the intent of the child. Then in `onResume` I use this info.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by onResume

Comment: Do you mean onActivityResult?

Comment: I'm a bit new ot Java as well. I was wondering why onResume is called automatically since I am not calling the function anywhere. All i've done is create teh function

Comment: @Liondancer quickly : those methods are called because when you create an activity you write `extends activity`. Which means all the methods required are automatically called and you just write the code that is custom to you. Every time you write `@override` before a method means you want to write your custom code for this method. That is why in all the `@Override` methods you call `super.` to be sure that the required code of the overridden method is performed as well as your custom code. Do you understand ?

Comment: I think I do. I just `onCreate` was sort of like my `main()` and that I needed to include functions in there for them to run.

Comment: @Liondancer when you @override you mean 'replace' a function that already exists. Note that for your terminology, what is a function is other languages is called a `method` in java. For the onCreate it already exist also, but as you want to link your layout to the activity you have to override it to link the layout and all that stuff, that is why it is some kind of an obligation to override it. But it is not exactly the same a the `main()`.

Comment: I see. What you jsut described about `@Override` I've read before but couldnt grasp it as wel. Youve made it much more clear to me thank you!

Comment: I am happy it helped. take care. see you

Answer (score 1):

For your concern you can utilize SharedPreferences

For ex: Put data in SP in second activity like this

```
SharedPreferences spppp = getSharedPreferences("tab", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editors = spppp.edit();
editors.putString("for", "0");
editors.commit();
```

and fetch data for list view in first activity like this

```
SharedPreferences spppp = getSharedPreferences("tab", 0);
String your_list_view_value = spppp.getString("for", "");
```