# I want to save my data of my android app

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite

I want to save my current data, whenever my application is closed!

Here is my piece of code, which is not working!

---

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){    
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);        
    outState.putDouble(TOTAL, total);
    outState.putDouble(CURRENT_VALUE , currVal);
    outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_VAL, billBeforeVal);            
}
```

---

Can i use sql, instead of this?

Comment: if you want to save small amount of data then you an go for `SharedPreferences` instead of creating DB.

Comment: Here are your options, with code samples: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Use shared Preferences instead. Check out my post for to know it's working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491764/returning-data-result-to-parent-activity-using-intents/20492029#20492029

Answer (score 0):

you can use android.content.SharedPreferences

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Edit: just see the comment of Ken Wolf for all the storage options...

Comment: Will it save data, when the application is crashed or stopped.